# How to show language item only by condition in Javascript React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next

I have a dropdown menu with two language options to select, russian and english. how to show only one option to choose, if another selected?  for example if site interface in Russian I must show only English and I must hide the language in which the site currently in. and Vice versa. By default in initial state of component the language must be in russian.

```
<NavDropdown eventKey={6} id="basic-nav-dropdowm" title=     {i18n.t('menu.dictionaries.label')}>

<MenuItem divider />
            {sysLangs.map((lang, index) => {

              return (
                <MenuItem
                  eventKey={`${7.9}.${index + 1}`}
                  key={'lang_' + lang.id}
                  onClick={() => this.handleSetLang(lang.key)}
                >
                  {lang.name}
                </MenuItem>
              );
            })}
            <MenuItem divider />


export const langs = [
{
  name: 'Русский',
  id: 1,
  key: 'ru'
 },
{
 name: 'English',
 id: 2,
 key: 'en'
},
{
 name: 'Қазақша',
 id: 3,
 key: 'kk'
}
 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run this code

```
const langs = [
{
  name: 'Русский',
  id: 1,
  key: 'ru'
 },
{
 name: 'English',
 id: 2,
 key: 'en'
},
{
 name: 'Қазақша',
 id: 3,
 key: 'kk'
}
 ];    

export const newLangs = langs.filter(lang => lang.name !== 'English') // replace English with the language of the page.
```